# Validate if file type is changed and uploaded

Tags: validation, file-upload

I am uploading multiple files from a page to a server. while doing so the validation for the file type is happening at server side and client side. Means the extesnion of the file type is checked and validated. If in case the user changes a .exe file to .doc file and uploads then how is it possible to trace this and validate.Is it possible to fetch using any header data or something like that?

Comment: Guys.. Can anyone guide me as to where am I missing out?